# I keep losing wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, internet-connection

I have a WRT54GL v1.1 wireless router and a WUSB54G v4 wireless adapter, both made by Linksys. The router is in the living room by the TV and the my computer is in the bedroom. My ISP is Brighthouse.

```
    Operating System
        Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
    CPU
        Intel Core 2 Duo E6600 @ 2.40GHz    36 °C
        Conroe 65nm Technology
    RAM
        3.00GB Single-Channel DDR2 @ 333MHz (5-4-4-14)
    Motherboard
        eMachines EMCP73VT-PM (CPU 1)   26 °C
    Graphics
        ASUS VS247 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        767MB GeForce GTX 460 (nVidia)  43 °C
    Hard Drives
        466GB Seagate ST350041 8AS SCSI Disk Device (SATA)  35 °C
    Optical Drives
        HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH41N SCSI CdRom Device
    Audio
        High Definition Audio Device
```

The problem is that my Internet connection will work fine for 15 minutes or so. Then the data will just stop flowing. Windows says I am still connected, and the systray icon still shows five bars. But Comodo Firewall will stop showing up and down traffic, and another of my systray applications complains about a lack of connection.

What I usually do is either disconnect from the network manually, or unplug and re-plug the USB adapter. At which point the connection will work properly for another 15 minutes. I've tried unplugging my router for 30 seconds and letting it reboot. I've also tried looking for a newer driver for my adapter but I seem to have the latest version 3.1.3.0.

This is a recent problem starting about a week ago. For the previous several months things were working just fine. I haven't made any changes to my system that I am aware of. The only thing I did was open my case to blow the dust out of it, then put everything back together.

How do I fix this issue?

[edit]

I've installed the DD-WRT firmware replacement, and successfully underclocked the device. However, the connection still drops frequently when uploading lots of data.

Answer (score 3):

The Linksys WRT54* series of routers is notorious for connection dropping issues related to:

- Overheating
- CPU utilization
- 2.4GHz channel interference
- Hardware failures (they don't last forever!)

You can find several threads on the issues:

- http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54G-keeps-dropping-wireless-connections/td-p/550294
- http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54GL-Wireless-connection-dropping-every-day-or-so/td-p/263676
- http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21473571-Wired-WRT54GL-dropping-internet-connection

My recommendations to you are first to try some basic troubleshooting steps:

- Try with a different computer if you can (rule out it being your operating system or PC hardware)
- Try using a different wireless adapter if you can
- Ensure you've updated the router and wireless adapter to use the latest firmware

If you're still getting nowhere, you might try a 3rd party firmware (DD-WRT, Tomato).

If after that you *still* haven't gotten anywhere, you've spent more hours than your time is worth, and you might just want to buy a new router ;)

Comment: Using DD-WRT (correct version, which is covered there - just pay attention to what you have) and using the "overclocking" function to slightly "underclock" it has let me get a bit more life from a WRT54-series device. But yes, they don't live forever.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I've had the same experience with them - underclocking seems to be the only way to keep them from glitching.

Comment: I've had the same experiences with these routers, but the issues didn't happen with DD-WRT, only with the factory firmware.  However, new firmware won't help if it's an overheating issue.

Comment: I've found that the android version of inssider (or the iphone one, I suppose) is REALLY useful in working out if you've got channel interference, and in deciding what's the best channel to use. Other than that, this answer covers everything I can think of ;). I've also found that the wrt54gl with third party firmware is rock solid, so switching to another firmware distro would be a very good idea. And yes, mine's going strong after something like 8-10 years so... they do last practically forever ;).

Comment: If there was a significant amount of dust in the port it may have been enough to disrupt normal communication flow between your computer and the adapter without having triggering it to be treated as disconnected.

Comment: It started happening again while trying to upload about 10GB worth of files to Google Drive. Will try the DD-WRT firmware and underclocking.

Comment: I installed the DD-WRT firmware and underclocked the router, but the signal still keeps dropping on large uploads. :(

Comment: @posfan12 invest in a new one -- they're just junk. I've gone through a handful; it's just not worth the time and effort to troubleshoot.

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall the drivers it works thats what i did.